# Magento block template file not loaded

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to do something very basic: edit a small part of the category product pager template. I copied `pager.phtml` from `.../base/default/template/page/html/` into my own theme's `template/page/html` folder and changed what I needed changed in the new file. Unfortunately, nothing is changed on the frontend.

I've tried enabling "Template Path Hints" and it definitely shows my custom template being loaded. When I blank out my theme's `pager.phtml`, all the content stays (as if its still loading the default template). When I edit the default template, still nothing changes! Ah ha! It must be cached...

But I've got the caches disabled (its a development site) and tried refreshing them all anyway. Nothing changes. I've edited many a template on this site and they've all worked as expected, its only `pager.phtml` that is giving me trouble.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or even toss a few more debugging ideas my way, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your caches are off, and you editing the `base/default` package/theme has no effect, it sounds like you are editing the wrong file ...

By chance is it a 1.3 template on a 1.4 build - as the pager set-up changed between the two versions and would lead to peculiar issues like you are describing.

Have you tested overriding another `.phtml` file to see if it actually works (ie. if you have set it up correctly).

Finally, caching being the last resort, have you got APC/Eaccelerator installed with the `mtime`/`stat` parameter set to false? As this would ignore the file modified time and serve up data directly from its internal cache. An Apache/PHP restart would prove this.

**Verify by running**

```
php -i | grep mtime
php -i | grep stat
```

Or by creating a test `phpinfo();` file

Comment: It was the wrong file.. granted the template path hints teased me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Tripple check the paths.  Seriously, something about working with Magento makes people (myself included) miss things that are one level below the obvious.

Once you've done that, jump to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
```

Find the lines that include the template file

```
$includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
    include $includeFilePath;
} else {
    Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
}
```

and add debugging code to figure out why your phtml isn't being included.

Comment: Turns out I needed to edit `catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml` and not `pager.phtml`. The template path hints had me confused! Thanks for the tip, and btw, the tutorials on your site are a godsend for magento devs. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Check your design settings in System->Config->General->Design->Package (example: default)
System->Config->General->Design->Themes->Default (set your theme directory name).

Answer (score -2):

Also try:

1. Reindexing (the template may be changed, but the old index may be loaded)
2. clean /var/cache folder itself.

Is the site using litespeed or any other caching utility? May have to clean those caches as well.

Comment: Re-indexing has nothing to do with templates / layouts. It is for catalogue only.

Comment: I wouldn't say it has 'nothing' to do with templates. It depends on what you're changing in the template. If you're updating something in the catalog in a template file, the changes aren't going to be visible until you reindex.

Comment: 1. You should never be changing anything from a `.phtml` file, it is for output only. 2. What you described is an infinite loop - to get a template to update, you need to re-index; but the template is the file prompting the re-index in the first place ...

Comment: You're right, you should never be doing stuff like that in a template file... but that doesn't mean that people don't. I do stuff I'm not supposed to in templates every single day, mostly for testing/development before I move things to proper module classes, but just because it's not best practice doesn't mean it's not useful or that people don't do it.

Comment: But your answer has nothing to do with the question. How would re-indexing help his template file display. **Indexes are for catalogue data only**

Comment: @sonassi Consider a template that outputs information from the catalog .

Comment: @AlanStorm - Of course, but it has nothing to do with the OP's question? His issue is unrelated to indexing.

Comment: @sonassi Hard to say. Chances are it doesn't, but weirder things have happened.

Comment: First, I never said it was going to fix the issue. Neither you nor I know the contents of his template file. However, wouldn't you agree that in some cases it's worth a shot to reindex? It's not difficult, and (in most cases) doesn't take that long.

Comment: @pspahn @AlanStorm To be honest, no, I do not think (***in this situation***) that a re-index will help. Editing his own package's version of `pager.html` had no effect **but** also editing the `base/default` version of `pager.html` **had no effect**. So he is either editing the wrong file ... or something else is afoot (aggressive OPCode caching etc.). **@pspahn** ***you are missing the point that his template file isn't loading in the first place*** - so it is irrelevant what it is doing ... let's hope I'm right, or I'll certainly look an argumentative fool!